# How do you fix with python - TypeError: must be str, nor int -?

Tags: python, typeerror, grok

```
def rotate(letter, key):
  new = ord(letter)
  new = chr(new) + key
  return new

new = rotate(" "," ")
print(new)
```

for some reason the code allows me to enter the message and key but then gives me the TypeError.

Comment: Could you provide input and expected output?

Comment: (input) -Word: - animal
(input) -Key: - 1
(output) bojnbm

Comment: So, you made a mistake in this line:
```new = chr(new) + key```
You're getting ```TypeError``` because in that place ```chr(new)``` is an ```str``` and ```key``` is an ```int```. 
If I'm getting this right, changing this line to:
```new = chr(new + key)```
should fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

`new` is the character code of `letter`. You should be adding to `new` *before* you convert it back to a character, not after.

```
new = chr(new + key)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am formatting your code correctly, I think that your code looks like the following:

```py
def rotate(letter, key):
    new = ord(letter)
    new = chr(new) + key
    return new
```

The `ord` function takes a letter and outputs the character code for that letter. The `chr` function takes a character code and turns it back into a letter. What's happened is that you are adding key to the letter, not to the number and you can't do that. I think that what you were expecting is that rather than having `chr(new) + key` you would have `chr(new + key)`. So the code would look as follows:

```py
def rotate(letter, key):
    new = ord(letter)
    new = chr(new + key)
    return new
```

This can be done shorter as well by combining the `chr`, `ord`, and `return`.

```py
def rotate(letter, key):
    return chr(ord(letter) + key)
```